# Grouping / Multilevel Prototype Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, prototype

```
    //What I would want:
    Num = function(){ 
        this.value = 10;
    }

    Num.prototype.calculate = {};
    Num.prototype.calculate.add = function(a){
        console.log(this.value + a);
    }
    Num.prototype.calculate.multi = function(a){
        console.log(this.value * a);
    }

    var myNum = new Num();

    myNum.calculate.add(1); //Error. "this" refers to Num.calculate and not Num itself.
                            //I would like to display 11

    ///////////////////////////////////////
    //My quick fix
    Num = function(){ 
        this.value = 10;
        this.calculate = new Calculate(this);
    }

    Calculate = function(parent){
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    Calculate.prototype.add = function(a){
        console.log(this.parent.value + a);
    }
    Calculate.prototype.multi = function(a){
        console.log(this.parent.value * a);
    }

    var myNum = new Num();

    myNum.calculate.add(1); //Display 11
```

Is doing multi-level functions/(grouping functions under an object and setting it as a prototype attribute) a good idea?
If not, is there a way to group/order functions so they don't all belong on the same "level"?
Or should it be avoid and there's a better way to do it?

Note: This is a very simplified example. In my project, something like this would NOT work even if it would work for this easy example:

```
    Num.prototype.calculate = function(operation,a){
        switch(operation){
            case 'add': console.log(this.value + a); break;
            case 'multi': console.log(this.value * a); break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about not defining `Num` as a constructor function and using a closure to access the `value` variable?

```
 num = function(val){ 
   var value = val || 10;
   return {
     calculate: {
       add: function (a) {
         value += a;
         console.log(value);
       },
       mul: function (a) {
         value *= a;
         console.log(value);
       }
     }
   };
 };


var n = num(42);

n.calculate.add(42); //84

n.calculate.mul(2); //168
```

This also makes `num` a **durable** object and `value` inaccessible from the outside. Only the members inside the `num` function have access to `value`. The downside to this approach is it makes `num` inextensible as it doesn't use the `this` object.

Comment: Interesting but not really what I'm looking for.